# Have three 3 numbers to work with. None match = 0, 2 match = 10, if all match = 20

Tags: python

This is my code, it's not returning 10 when only two out of the three numbers match.

```
def green_ticket_value(a, b, c):
  if a != b or b != c or a != c:
    return 0
  elif a == b and a != c or b == c and b != a or a == c and a!= b:
    return 0 
  else: a == b == c
  return 20
```

Comment: There is no `return 10` in your function. Typo?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the second "return 0" should be "return 10".

Second of all, *(this may or may not have an impact)*, you might need parentheses in the elif line.

```
def green_ticket_value(a, b, c):
    if a != b or b != c or a != c:
        return 0
    elif (a == b and a != c) or (b == c and b != a) or (a == c and a!= b):
        return 10 # NOT 0
    else: a == b == c
        return 20
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that too, it certainly makes it more clear what he's trying to do (and makes sure that that's what's actually happening). It's worth noting that the above statement is still always false though because a == c, b == a, and a == b by virtue of "a != b or b != c or a != c" being false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the first if statement logic. You are using `or` instead of `and` which is why you never compare the second statement.

assuming `a=1` `b=2` and `c=2`
in your current code it is true that a !=b therefore is a valid statement and it returns 0
It should be:

```
def green_ticket_value(a, b, c):
    if a != b and b != c and a != c:
    #rest of code
```

you can also use a different method which is to use counter and return the most common value

```
from collections import Counter

def green_ticket_value(*args):
    green = Counter(args)
    values = {1:0,2:10,3:20}
    return values[green.most_common(1)[0][1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way. If

```
a != b or b != c or a != c
```

is false, then

```
a == b and b == c and a == c
```

[DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) explain why this is the case. Remember that

```
~(A \/ B) <-> ~A /\ ~B
~(A /\ B) <-> ~A \/ ~B
```

Where [<->](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) basically means "equivalent to each other", `~` means "not," `\/` means "or", and `/\` means "and."

To go through this code:

```
def green_ticket_value(a, b, c):
    if a != b or b != c or a != c:
       return 0
    # It can *never* be the case that a != c or a != b at this point
    elif a == b and a != c or b == c and b != a or a == c and a!= b:
      return 0 // Should this be "return 10"?
   # What did you mean to do here?
   else: a == b == c
       return 20
```

It's a little unclear whether you meant

```
a == b and a != c or b == c and b != a or a == c and a!= b
```

to mean

```
(a == b and a != c) or (b == c and b != a) or (a == c and a!= b)
```

which will always be false (a == c and a == b, which means that *all* of these conditions are false), or the following:

```
a == b and (a != c or b == c) and (b != a or a == c) and a!= b
```

which is also always false (in fact, it's self-refuting because it contains `a == b && a != b`) or if you meant some other variant. I'd **strongly** recommend using parenthases here to make it more clear what you're trying to do.

Also, for the last part:

```
(b == c and b != a) or (a == c and a != b)
```

`a != b` and `b != a` mean the exact same thing, so the above statement means the same thing as

```
a != b and (a == c or b == c)
```